# How to compile less css files using brunch

Tags: css, compilation, less, brunch

I'm looking for the best way to compile the less files using brunch. Since I'd like to do it in the server side, I was thinking that I have to compile using a bash script (or something like that).

I noticed that there is a plugin for using less + brunch, but I'm not sure how to use it. I'd be great if I could edit the less files and get an automatically update when the brunch watch --server is running

Anyone knows how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the info from the official site:

http://brunch.io/#plugins-list

1.

> To install new plugin, simply execute `npm install --save plugin-name`. This will install its node.js dependencies and save to package.json.

2.

> All plugins are available at the [Plugins wiki page](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/wiki/Plugins).

3.

> https://github.com/brunch/less-brunch

4.

> npm install --save less-brunch

Comment: Hi Paul thanks for your reply (btw, great work with brunch.io) I know the steps you've mentioned bellow are for installing a plugin on brunch, but my question is regarding if doing it, when a .less file is updated at /app it allows to the /public/css/file.css is automatically updated as well?

Comment: Not sure I understand. When you change files in `app`, stuff in `public` auto-recompiles. Is that it?

Comment: Exactly, Is it possible?

Comment: It is core concept of brunch. Of course it is possible, brunch does it every time you change stuff by default.